# Angular JS - Perimeter Search

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

i am planing a relaunch of a current website which is based on a CMS (PHP/SQL). 
The site is pretty simple: You can search companies based on a ZIP you enter. The latitude and longitude is currently encoded by a PHP API for Googlemaps.

Now we plan to refactor the site and build it on Angular.

May main question is:
Can Angular do any kind of same as my following PHP function does?
I want to read a json file with all that data instead of query a MySQL Database. So i can get rid of the CMS and PHP stuff.

```
public static function searchCompanies($lat, $lng, $group = null){
    $sql        = WV_SQL::getInstance();
    $query = 'SELECT id, status, detail, company, latitude ,longitude,
    street, number, zip, city, urlkey, internet, email, productgroup,
    ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )
        AS distance FROM sly_km6_companies WHERE status="1" HAVING distance < 50  ORDER BY distance LIMIT  10;';
    $addresses  = $sql->getArray($query);
    return $addresses;  
}
```

many thanks!